# Microsoft software product keys finder

Tags: windows, microsoft-office-2010, licensing

We have to give to Microsoft all our Microsoft software installations with product keys. Is there a software that can scan a network, or at least that it can be started from command line and save Microsoft product keys to a txt or csv file?

We have tried MSIA and it didn't work, we used jelly bean key finder but it doesn't detected the difference between office home and business 2010 and office professional 2010.

Comment: You use MSIA, like Microsoft told you to do. If it "doesn't work" then you fix it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: This question is more focused on the tools that we need to use for Windows environment, while the question you referenced is more general.

Comment: We use [VAMT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824953.aspx), but we only need to inventory Windows and Office installs.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [ProduKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html). It can scan whole network (whole domain or a range of IP addresses) and store results in txt file.

Comment: Nice tool, but doesn't retrieve product keys for Windows 7 with Volume Licensing and Windows Server 2008 (R2) hosts.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Spiceworks to scan your network for all software and hardware, you can the run a report against the PCs to get back any microsoft software, you can then download the report as CSV.

http://www.spiceworks.com/

Spiceworks will also keep the list up to date and can set up alerts to tell you when you have installed more licenses than you own, you can also use it to find software you have installed but aren't actually using.